# AngularJs Sort orderBy not working properly in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Sorting not working properly on my inputField. After clicking on the `inputField` column, values got sorted, but problem is sorting not correct for modified values, all values are going bottom. I'm adding `model-change-blur` to sort after the blur in to text box. I don't know where I'm doing wrong. After modified values.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 65px;">
                <div href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'id'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                    ID <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortType=='id'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':sortReverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!sortReverse}"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 65px;">
                <div href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'checkBoxField'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                    Checked <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortType=='checkBoxField'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':sortReverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!sortReverse}"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 61px;">
                <div href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'inputField'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                    Input <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortType=='inputField'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':sortReverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!sortReverse}"></span>
                </div>
            </th> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in filtered = ( tableData | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse )" id="row-{{$index}}">
                <td align="center" style="width: 68px;">{{row.id}}</td>
                <td align="center" style="width: 68px;"><input id="checkBoxField-{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="row.checkBoxField" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/></td>
                <td align="center" style="width: 61px;"><input id="inputField-{{$index}}" class="onlyNumber" type="text" ng-model="row.inputField" maxlength="3"style="width: 50px;" model-change-blur></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

And here is my Js file:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.sortType     = ''; 
    $scope.sortReverse  = false; 

    $scope.tableData = [];
    for(i=1; i<= 8; i++){
        $scope.tableData.push({"id":i,"checkBoxField": i%3==0 ,"inputField":1+i});
    }   
})
.directive('modelChangeBlur', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (attr.type === 'radio' || attr.type === 'checkbox') return;

            elm.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                });         
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Update: Adding Images**

Without sorting table looks like below:

[image]

After sorting table ascending order looks like below:

[image]

After modified 3rd row order looks like below here is issue:

[image]

Modified value going to bottom row.

Comment: You want to sort data after i am leave textbox right?

Comment: @PareshGami yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sort code is fine.. just change the input type to number..

```
<input  id="inputField-{{$index}}" class="onlyNumber" type="number" ng-model="row.inputField" maxlength="3" style="width: 50px;" model-change-blur> </td>
```

you just have an empty default sort column, just change this to define a default value. you can check by clicking one of the table head column and it'll sort properly.

```
$scope.sortType     = 'inputField';
```

or you can add `ng-init` to your `table` tag like.

```
ng-init = "sortType='inputField'"
```

I'd also suggest to define an `order` function for a cleaner markup.

```
// code source https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy
$scope.sort = function(sortType) {
    $scope.sortReverse = ($scope.sortType === sortType) ? !$scope.sortReverse : false;
    $scope.sortType = sortType;
  };
```

and simply in your Markup, instead of

```
ng-click="sortType = 'inputField'; sortReverse = !sortReverse"
```

this

```
ng-click="sort('inputField')"
```

and initial code to either

```
ng-init = "sort('inputField')"
```

or

```
sort('inputField')
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zOfCCMs6Tow4ZV7sq87Q?p=preview)

Comment: by default.. it is empty.. my code is there on click on column I'm setting value `ng-click="sortType = 'inputField'; sortReverse = !sortReverse"`

Comment: @Rajesh you know blur is called when you click something else.. type something and click out of the box and it'll sort accordingly.. only if there is a sortType defined..

Comment: @Rajesh I have produced a simple plunk check it out.. didn't change much of your code.. but the code worked from the start..

Comment: in your plunk example also if i modified middle values(Input column) that are not sorting correctly.

Comment: @Rajesh dude modify than click something else. that's what blur event is about... you need to click away from the input box to trigger blur event

Comment: @Rajesh try the plunk now

Comment: I modified input type text to number working fine. Please update your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one also

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

I just make one function which is call when you leave from textbox.

```
$scope.changeData = function(predicate)
{
    $scope.sortType = 'inputField'
    $scope.sortReverse = true;
}
```

and here check how ng-blur call

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in filtered = ( tableData | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse )" id="row-{{$index}}">
        <td align="center" style="width: 68px;">{{row.id}}</td>

        <td align="center" style="width: 68px;">
            <input id="checkBoxField-{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="row.checkBoxField" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/>
        </td>

        <td align="center" style="width: 61px;">
            <input id="inputField-{{$index}}" ng-blur="changeData(sortReverse)" class="onlyNumber" type="text" ng-model="row.inputField" maxlength="3"style="width: 50px;" model-change-blur>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: If possible please put it in jsfiddle or Plunker

Comment: After modified the value I'm clicking on column header again, still that is not sorting properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
 //change syntax of ng-repeat as follows  
  <tr ng-repeat="row in filtered = ( tableData | orderBy:'-id' )" id="row-{{$index}}">
 // add - for reverse sorting
```

Comment: I want sort `inputField`

Answer (score -1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in filtered = ( tableData | orderBy:'-inputField' )" id="row-{{$index}}">
```

Comment: not working..Please test and post your answer.. Thank you.

Comment: It is working at my end, I have tested it before posting.

Comment: please modify the `inputField` column values and that values not sorting properly.